# The bundle “MyProjectUITests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I'm willing to add unit and UI tests to my app.

I first configured unit tests with success, I tried to do the same with UI tests. Here is my Podfile, after adding a new UI Testing Bundle target :

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
inhibit_all_warnings!

def shared_pods
pod 'Bolts'
pod 'Branch'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'Toast-Swift'
end

target 'MyTarget' do
shared_pods
end

target 'MyTargetUITests' do
shared_pods
end

target 'MyTargetUnitTests' do
shared_pods
end
```

However, when I try to run the automatically created `MyProjectUITests` test case, which only contains the basic setup and without even a `@testable import MyProject`:

```
import XCTest

class MyProjectUITests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        continueAfterFailure = false
        XCUIApplication().launch()
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Running tests...
>   The bundle “MyProjectUITests” couldn’t be loaded because it is damaged or missing necessary resources. Try reinstalling the bundle.
>
> (dlopen_preflight(/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5A1FE39F-E675-4A47-9BF4-FBCDB96F5821/MyProjectUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyProjectUITests.xctest/MyProjectUITests): Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
>
> Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/5A1FE39F-E675-4A47-9BF4-FBCDB96F5821/MyProjectUITests-Runner.app/PlugIns/MyProjectUITests.xctest/Frameworks/Toast_Swift.framework/Toast_Swift
>
> Reason: image not found)

What is wrong? Thanks for your help.

**EDIT** : for information, it works fine when I remove that `Toast_swift` pod from my UI test target and let it only in my app and unit test targets.

Comment: CMD + Shift + K

Comment: I've already tried this, with no success. (see the edit in my post)

Comment: Are you using xCode 10?

Comment: @JonVogel Yes exactly, version 10.0.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8139) on the cocoapods github issue tracker.

I'm still a little confused as to why this became a problem but the setting the `ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES` to `YES` using this script fixed the issue for me.

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            # This works around a unit test issue introduced in Xcode 10.
            # We only apply it to the Debug configuration to avoid bloating the app size
            if config.name == "Debug" && defined?(target.product_type) && target.product_type == "com.apple.product-type.framework"
                config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = "YES"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: I also read the issue and tried this, but I keep getting this error. It only happens in UI tests, not even in unit ones. So I ended up pasting the framework code into my UI test target, but it's really not convenient..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding *inherit! :search_paths*

and also changing *ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES in post_install*

```
use_frameworks!

def shared_pods
    pod 'SomePod'
end

target 'App_name' do
    shared_pods
end

target 'App_nameTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    shared_pods
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = 'YES'
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I too faced this issue and none of the other suggestions worked.

After a while I found out that specifically using `print()` anywhere in your code will somehow force libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to be loaded and the issue will go away.

I'm using Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2 and the pod that was giving me this issue was Nimble.

Hope this helps!