# "Copy swift standard libraries" build step does not include SwiftOnoneSupport.dylib

Tags: swift, build, cocoapods, standard-library

I have been experiencing a troubling problem lately that has to do with the running of tests on a project which has a cocoapods dependency to a framework which crashed at runtime with error:

> Library not loaded: @rpath/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib
>   Referenced from: MyCocoapodsDependency

There are other stackoverflow topics out there about that particular problem but none of them address root cause (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40986082/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libswiftswiftononesupport-dylib)), which is that during the "Copy swift standard libraries" step of the test build, the missing library is not copied over.

It looks like this (this is the build log when I build the tests):

[image: missing dylib]

When it should look like this (this is the build log for a test app that uses the exact same dependencies):

[image]

OnOneSupport seems to have to do with with a project setting that has to do with "Whole module optimization".

[image]

But even if I change to "not onOne" it doesn't make a difference. The dylib is referred to in https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/cmake/modules/AddSwift.cmake

I cannot for the life of me figure out why it's omitted from the standard libraries build step for one target and not for another, but its obvious that my tests needs it. Anybody know how I can force the compiler to include SwiftOnoneSupport?

**Workaround**

Add a build phase to the test target (in the project file) that copies libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to Frameworks. The dylib can be found at:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/bitcode_strip /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator/libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib

[image]

Comment: Take a look at my answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54034898/191744
adding inherit! :search_paths and changing embedded swift libs in post_install worked for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this same issue with two of my frameworks. The strangest thing was that everything was working fine with one of them but not with the other.

While I wasn't able to figure out why this happens (since it seems to be an [Xcode bug](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8318)), I was able to find a pretty neat workaround.

Turns out that using `print()` anywhere in your code will somehow force libswiftSwiftOnoneSupport.dylib to be loaded. So, by adding something like this the problem should go away:

```
private func dummy() { 
    print("Hello world!") 
}
```

I'm using Xcode 10.1, Swift 4.2 and the pod that was giving me this issue was Nimble.

Hope this helps!